# Make error when cross compiling protobuf for ARM:./.libs/libprotoc.so: error: undefined reference to 'descriptor

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling

Make error when cross compiling protobuf for ARM

## compiled script:

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 
  3 export PREFIX=$HOME/soft/protobuf_arm/
  4 CLANG_TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/soft/arm-29-toolchain-clang
  5 export PATH=$CLANG_TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
  6 export SYSROOT=$CLANG_TOOLCHAIN/sysroot
  7 export CC="armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang --sysroot $SYSROOT"
  8 export CXX="armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang++ --sysroot $SYSROOT"
  9 
 10 cd $HOME/github/c++/protobuf
 11 make clean
 12 ./autogen.sh
 13 ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
 14 --host=armv7a-linux-androideabi29 \
 15 --with-sysroot="${SYSROOT}" \
 16 --enable-shared \
 17 --enable-cross-compile \
 18 --with-protoc=$HOME/soft/protobuf_linux/protoc \
 19 CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -D__ANDROID_API__=29" \
 20 CXXFLAGS="-frtti -fexceptions -march=armv7-a -D__ANDROID_API__=29" \
 21 LIBS="-llog -lz -lc++_static"
 22 make -j 12
 23 make install
```

## There is no error in configure, error in make:

```
In file included from google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_source_generator_base.cc:39:
./google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_source_generator_base.h:62:25: warning: private field 'descriptor_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
  const FileDescriptor* descriptor_;
                        ^
1 warning generated.
  CXXLD    libprotoc.la
clang90++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang90++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  CXXLD    protoc
./.libs/libprotoc.so: error: undefined reference to 'descriptor_table_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto'
./.libs/libprotoc.so: error: undefined reference to 'scc_info_FileDescriptorProto_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto'
clang90++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Makefile:3883: protoc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sen/github/c++/protobuf/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1866: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sen/github/c++/protobuf'
make: *** [Makefile:1773: all] Error 2
```

## Environment

```
Linux x 5.6.15-arch1-1
GNU Make 4.3
NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462
protobuf v3.13.0
```

What is interesting is that although an error was reported, library files such as .so were obtained under protobuf/src/.libs.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

This is may be a bit involved, but it could be as simple as:

- add `-fuse-ld=bfd` to `CFLAGS`
- add `-fuse-ld=bfd` to `CXXFLAGS`

If doing that doesn't fix the problem, then you may need to also:

- after `./autogen.sh` but before `./configure` patch `ltmain.sh` to allow use of `-fuse-ld=bfd` (patch file below)

#### Patch file (`ltmain.sh.patch`):

```
--- a/ltmain.sh 2015-02-16 04:15:37.000000000 +1100
+++ b/ltmain.sh 2021-05-23 18:18:46.000000000 +1000
@@ -7273,9 +7273,11 @@
       # --sysroot=*          for sysroot support
       # -O*, -g*, -flto*, -fwhopr*, -fuse-linker-plugin GCC link-time optimization
       # -stdlib=*            select c++ std lib with clang
+      # -fuse-ld=*           Linker select flags for GCC
       -64|-mips[0-9]|-r[0-9][0-9]*|-xarch=*|-xtarget=*|+DA*|+DD*|-q*|-m*| \
       -t[45]*|-txscale*|-p|-pg|--coverage|-fprofile-*|-F*|@*|-tp=*|--sysroot=*| \
-      -O*|-g*|-flto*|-fwhopr*|-fuse-linker-plugin|-fstack-protector*|-stdlib=*)
+      -O*|-g*|-flto*|-fwhopr*|-fuse-linker-plugin|-fstack-protector*|-stdlib=*| \
+      -fuse-ld=*)
         func_quote_for_eval "$arg"
    arg=$func_quote_for_eval_result
         func_append compile_command " $arg"
```

#### Patch command:

```
patch -p1 < path/to/ltmain.sh.patch
```

### Long answer

The issue is due to the symbols being exported weakly from in `src/.libs/libprotobuf.so` which goes against the mapping configuration provided in `src/libprotobuf.map`. This configuration specifies that all symbols that match the pattern `*google*` should be exported strongly (and thus are available for linking into `protoc`) whereas all others should be hidden.

However, there is a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24527) in the default linker (GOLD) that is used when running `armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang++`, which ignores any mapping directive inside the `extern "C++"` block. Within the NDK there are three linkers provided:

- `ld`
- `ld.bfd`
- `ld.gold`

The BFD linker does not have the same issue, so the path forward is to configure `armv7a-linux-androideabi29-clang++` to use the BFD linker, and that is what the `-fuse-ld=bfd` option does.

Unfortunately, this may not quite so straightforward, as the protobuf source is built using [`libtool`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) and the latest released version does not recognise the `-fuse-ld` argument. Thus, if your distro version of `libtool` hasn't applied the patch to their packaged version, we need to apply a change to allow it to do so (partially taken from a [development commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libtool.git/commit/build-aux/ltmain.in?id=f9970d99293faf908fdc153a653fa5781095fb7a)). The least invasive way to do this is to wait until the necessary file (`ltmain.sh`) has been copied into the source as part of the `./autogen.sh` command, and then patch it so that when that file is processed (as part of the `./configure` command) the change propagates into the created `libtool` file.

### What about `aarch64-linux-android29`?

When building with `aarch64-linux-android29-clang++`, the default linker has been changed to the BFD linker, so for a codebase like protobuf this issue just won't occur. Using the same patch above, you can replicate the issue using `-fuse-ld=gold`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this error too when compiling on Linux (debian 4.19.0-16-amd64) for `armv7a-linux-androideabi`

As you said, it's "ok" cause the libs are created in `src/.libs` and they seem to work fine (at least `libprotobuf.so`)

I didn't have the issue using an old version of the ndk-r21 (Pkg.Revision = 21.0.6113669)
I updated recently to the latest ndk-r21e (21.4.7075529) where I've discovered is the issue...

PS: this is not happening for `aarch64-linux-android`
Here is a link [on Qt forum on the topic](https://forum.qt.io/topic/108704/building-protobuff-libs-for-android-64-bit-arm64-v8a-qt-5-12-4/24).

For those interested, [here is my compile script](https://github.com/mbruel/ClementineRemote/blob/main/protobuf-3.13.0/compile.sh) to build the x86_64 version and both Android 32 and 64 bits.